# Cache set of web pages in a webview android

Tags: android, caching, webview

I am developing a web app and I will also be using a WebView App in Android, I want to cache some set of pages to provide offline access to my users. Right now only those pages are cached which I visit once, but I want to pre-cache a set of pages so that users can work offline.

The code I am using now:

```
private WebView webView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.webView = (WebView)
            findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

    String appCachePath;
    appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    // Enable responsive layout
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    // Zoom out if the content width is greater than the width of the viewport
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null || !cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
    {
        Log.i("B","INSIDE NO NETWORK");
        appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        webSettings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);

        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("A","INSIDE YES NETWORK");
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hey, you found any solution?

Comment: No, I am not using webview now, after a little RnD, I found that pwa to be more useful for my use case, hence I will doing caching using serviceworkers @akki

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class XXXWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        if ("https://www.example.com".equals(url)) {
            String mimeType;//the resource response's MIME type, for example text/html
            String encoding;//the resource response's encoding
            Inputstream is;//cache of pages
            ...
            return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType,codeing,is);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```